# Remove duplicate data passed from input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a input field that accepts numbers. I turn each number to an array on keyup and display them in a div. The issue now is when displaying it displays like this:

```
1
1
2
1
1
2
3
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // turn input to array
  var inputs = $('#input');
  
  inputs.keyup(function() {
    var input = $('#input').val().split('');
    // remove empty values
    input = input.filter(function(el) {
      return el.length != 0;
    });

    //loop through input array
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      // if input is not a number
      if (isNaN(input[i])) {
        // remove the character
        input.splice(i, 1);
      }
      // remove duplicate value in array
      if (input.indexOf(input[i]) != i) {
        input.splice(i, 1);
      }

      // add to a div id
      $('#numbers').append('<h3 class="H3-em9z5i-0 CodeField__InputCode-sc-1270tiq-1 huhlDl cpSCaJ">' + input[i] + '</h3>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd use a `Set` instead of an array. Sets contain unique values.

Comment: if (input.indexOf(input[i]) != i) {
                            input.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                           
above code is wrong, try with following

if (input.indexOf(input[i]) != -1) {
                            input.splice(i, 1);
                        }

or 

input = input.filter(function(element,index,self){
            return index === self.indexOf(element); 
        });

Comment: @pramodkadam seemed it work but it return undefined, i dont want to prevent user from putting in same number just that the output returns new array instead of appending

Comment: like this
["1"]
["1", "2"]

Comment: @PreciousOladele do you want output like the above? then your logic is wrong.

Comment: how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you need to do 3 things:

- Remove Old Printed Values (in the `#number` element)
- Remove Empty Values with a Regex (or by checking for an Empty String)
- Remove Duplicates from Array with a `[...Set(Arr)]` operation.

See [working example here in CodePen here](https://codepen.io/chizaram-igolo/pen/poaVwYg).

### Remove Old Printed Values

Remove old values by calling `.html("")` or more directly `.empty()` on `#numbers` (The former calls the latter, so they do the same thing). Place this call at the beginning of the **`keyup`** event handler to erase previously printed content in the `#numbers` element before proceeding to print new input values.

```
inputs.keyup(function () {
    $('#numbers').html(""); 
    ... 
}
```

### Remove Empty Values with a Regex (or by checking for an Empty String)

The regex pattern for empty spaces of any length is `/\s+/` where `\s` is a space character and `+` means 1 or more space characters. The `g` flag in the `string.replace()` method indicates a global search and replace operation. Then call `.split()` after replacing removing empty spaces.

```
inputs.keyup(function () {
    $('#numbers').html("");

    var input = $('#input').val(); 

    // remove empty values
    var input = input.replace(/\s+/g, "").split(''); 
    ... 
}
```

Alternatively, you may do it this way:

```
inputs.keyup(function () {
    $('#numbers').html("");

    var input = $('#input').val().split('');
    // remove empty values
    input = input.filter(function (el) {
        return el !== "";
    }); 
   ...
}
```

And not `el.length != 0` because each element in the array after the split is at least one character long.

### Remove Duplicates from Array with the a `[...Set(Arr)]` operation

Use the `Set()` constructor to create a new set from the old array with all duplicates removed then convert the set back to an array with `[...Set(Arr)]`:

```
//loop through input array
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    // if input is not a number
    if (isNaN(input[i])) {
        // remove the character
        input.splice(i, 1);
    }
    // remove duplicate value in array
   input = [...new Set(input)] 
   ... 
 }
```

### Altogether Now

**Runnable Code Snippet Below:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  
  // turn input to array
  var inputs = $('#input');
  inputs.keyup(function () {
   $('#numbers').html("");
    
    var input = $('#input').val().split('');  
    console.log(input);
    // remove empty values
    // var input = input.replace(/\s+/g, "").split('');  
    input = input.filter(function (el) {
            return el !== "";
        });
   
    //loop through input array
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      // if input is not a number
      if (isNaN(input[i])) {
        // remove the character
        input.splice(i, 1);
      }
      // remove duplicate value in array
      input = [...new Set(input)]

      // add to a div id
      $('#numbers').append('<h3 class="H3-em9z5i-0 CodeField__InputCode-sc-1270tiq-1 huhlDl cpSCaJ">' + input[i] + '</h3>');
    }

    console.log(input);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <div id="numbers"></div> 
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to just "clear" the "#numbers" div before appending. That way you will not have those duplicated (old values).

```
$('#numbers').html("")
```

**Demo***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // turn input to array
  var inputs = $('#input');
  inputs.keyup(function() {
    var input = $('#input').val().split('');
    // remove empty values
    input = input.filter(function(el) {
      return el.length != 0;
    });

    $('#numbers').html("")
    //loop through input array
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      // if input is not a number
      if (isNaN(input[i])) {
        // remove the character
        input.splice(i, 1);
      }
      // remove duplicate value in array
      if (input.indexOf(input[i]) != i) {
        input.splice(i, 1);
      }

      // add to a div id
      $('#numbers').append('<h3 class="H3-em9z5i-0 CodeField__InputCode-sc-1270tiq-1 huhlDl cpSCaJ">' + input[i] + '</h3>');
    }

    console.log(input);

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="number" />
<div id="numbers"></div>
```